# AWS Console- copy tag to tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, keys

Two tags in AWS Console. Tag Key name: test1 and test2. All the tag information is in test1 key but need to go to test2 key. In filter I can type tag:all then edit that tag with a different key. However with 150+ instances this would take a while. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't read anything about copying tags using the console. You can do most things via scripting and the API, but it's probably quicker to just copy and paste manually.

Comment: Yep, Tim is correct. There's nothing in the API to do this. However, at max, it's a ~10 line bash or python script to iterate through all of your instances and make the change.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Tag editor to do this activity. Of course, it's not like you wanted, moving one tag to other BUT it will provide a single interface where you can copy and paste within 10-15 minutes (lesser than writing automation script) if its just one-time activity.

Please check [here](https://www.justdocloud.com/2018/10/07/tag-aws-resources-efficiently-effectively/) how to use the Tag editor and efficient tagging information in general.